# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, tomcat7

I get the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory

I have added the relevant `jars` `commons-dbcp-1.4.jar` and `commons-pool-1.4.jar` but the error isn't resolved.

#### Stacktrace:

> Stack trace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>     org.apache.jsp.ozLogin_jsp._jspService(ozLogin_jsp.java:470)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
>     org.apache.jsp.ozLogin_jsp._jspService(ozLogin_jsp.java:189)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1163)
>     org.apache.jsp.ozLogin_jsp._jspService(ozLogin_jsp.java:189)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Can you provide more information about your project? I assume it is a web project, are you using maven?

Comment: Yes it is web project and yes I am using maven

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml?

Comment: what exactly you need from pom.xml

Comment: How it is declared those depencies... commons-dbcp-1.4 and commons-pool-1.4.

Comment: <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.2</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: I commented the maven because of the error and added those jar files still the error

Comment: Everything sounds OK with maven. Try to clean the temporary folders on tomcat (logs, temp, work) and try redeploy the application once again.

Comment: Did not work same error but instead of .WsFilter now it says CorsFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the jars to the Tomcat lib folder fixed the error for me